# не работает onclick на диве

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(".div").click(function() {
  $(".div").addClass("open");
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.open {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <span class="span">
    fgfggh
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Если подключить забытый jQuery, то всё отлично работает

Comment: работает же ...фон у блок становится синий